# Get Google Cloud Endpoints API usage data by API key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, saas

I'm looking recommended ways to extract usage data by API key for a given set of Google Cloud Endpoints APIs. The project bills customers the usage of a certain API.

My goal is to know how many times each client calls each of the ESP apis in a given month so that they can be billed based on their usage.

#### Example

- client_a:

  - api-key: 12345
- client_b:

  - api-key: 67890

---

- ESP1:

  - api_esp1
- ESP2:

  - api_esp2_foo
  - api_esp2_bar

---

Ultimately, I want to know how many times `client_a` used each of the available ESP APIs, and how many times `client_b` used them.

One (part of the) solution is to create a GCP project per client as outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys#sharing_apis_protected_by_api_key). I didn't figure out how to go from there though.

Comment: I think that following the diagram that you shared you should be following the steps on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys#create-a-separate-google-cloud-project-for-each-caller) to keep implementing the solution.

Comment: Exactly. I'm wondering though if I get absolute numbers that I can track long term.

Comment: I believe that with their monitoring tools, it can be tracked as mentioned at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/monitoring-your-api#filter_for_a_specific_consumer_project), so the monitoring tools can be used to track this as far as I understand

Comment: The provided solutions linked above don't provide monitoring usage for longer than 30 days. Maybe I just didn't find it. Went ahead and started storing usage data. I'll be using the options provided by Luis for short term monitoring to receive alerts for anomaly detection

Comment: I have a similar usecase: I need to monitor customer monthly API usage based on HTTP headers (similarly to your case with API Keys). Have you found a suitable solution through Cloud endpoints or any other product ? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not through Cloud Endpoints. Our use case has shifted so that we only need 30 days of API monitoring and long term API use is tracked separately. Depending on your use case you could use a permanent storage solution (database) or google analytics + biq query.